# creating entity beans

Tags: persistence, ejb, java-ee-6, entity-bean

[image: Class diagram of the customer order application]

i want to create a java EE application (bean container and web container) in netbeans to store customer and order details.
one customer can have many orders.but order contains only one customer.
1)should be able to view order details with customer no and customer name.
1)should be able to update customer and order details.

i have already created two beans but i cant update or delete customer details and orders.
 [image: CustomerEntity]

[image: CustomerOrderEntity]

Comment: How are you trying update or delete details?

Comment: Do you have persistence unit? Entity manager?

Comment: yes ,i have a entity manager in customer facade and order facade.

Comment: and i want to insert and delete details with a servlet.